# How to remove domain name from the src URL attribute in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fetching img src attribute into a variable, while doing so I'm getting the complete url of the image, i want to remove domain name from the url

```
var imgurl = "http://nitseditor.dev/img/home/bg.jpg";
```

I want to have only `img/home/bg.jpg`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is the domain always the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get substring by getting the index of third `/`.

```js
var imgurl = "http://nitseditor.dev/img/home/bg.jpg";

console.log(
  imgurl.substr(imgurl.indexOf('/', 7) + 1)
);
```

Comment: thanks. Does it have IE support as @Tushar's answer in not supporting IE.

Comment: @NitishKumar [YES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: This is not very stable

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor.

> This is an experimental technology

```
var url = new URL(imgurl);
console.log(url.pathname);
```

```js
var imgurl = "http://nitseditor.dev/img/home/bg.jpg";
var url = new URL(imgurl);
console.log(url.pathname);
```

[**Browser Support**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: If IE is not your friend, this seems to be the best answer so far!

Comment: I think this is the [polyfill](https://github.com/arv/DOM-URL-Polyfill)

Comment: @Rayon Thanks, [This](https://github.com/Polymer/URL/blob/master/url.js) can be used for older browsers.

Answer (score 7):

```
url = url.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '')
```

Comment: this will remove all the `/` string. Not appropriate for my question.

Comment: you try run code above it have result is: /img/home/bg.jpg